# How to produce a Chi-square distribution table With p-values for three vectors (two categorical and one numeric) using a function in R

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, chi-squared, probability-theory

**Issue**

I have a list with three vectors where `two are categorical (Whistle_Type and Country)` and one is `numeric (counts of whistle types A-F)` (**see below**), which I produced using `dplyr() with the count() function` (**see below**). I want to run a `Chi-Square test` to determine if there are any significant differences between `whistle types` among the countries `Germany and France`

I want to create a `distribution table` using a `function` showing the p-values to conduct a Chi-square test. I would like to produce something like this.

**Desired Distribution table with p-values**

```
                          A  B  C  D  E  F
                   France p  p  p  p  p  p
                  Germany p  p  p  p  p  p

                   *p stands for p-values
```

**I can't quite figure out how to manipulate the function to produce the outcome that I would like. I don't understand this error message as I am incorporating both a dataframe and list into the function**

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = as.formula(paste(x, " ~ Country")),  : 
  'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list
Called from: model.frame.default(formula = as.formula(paste(x, " ~ Country")), 
    data = Count.Whistle.type_ChiSq$n)
```

If anyone is able to help (**see the reproducible data frame below**), I would be deeply appreciative

**R code**

```
Produce a list showing counts of whistle types per country using the function count()

Count.Whistle.type_ChiSq <- Whistle_Parameters %>% dplyr::count(Whistle_Type, Country)
Count.Whistle.type_ChiSq

List of counts of whistle types per country

       Whistle_Type Country   n
1             A      France  90
2             A      Germany 70
3             B      France  34
4             B      Germany 10
5             C      France  24
6             C      Germany  9
7             D      France  44
8             D      Germany 25
9             E      France  21
10            E      Germany 39
11            F      France  25
12            F      Germany 32
    

Chi-Square function

#List of acoustic parameters to conduct a Chi-squre test
Outcomes_Whistle_Types<-c("A", "B","C", "D", "E", "F")

#Eliminate the duplicate rows present in the vector country
Country <- unique(Parameters$Country)

#Prodcue a distribution table with p-values for the Chi Square test
Chi_Whistle<-sapply(Outcomes_Whistle_Types, \(x) chisq.test(xtabs(as.formula(paste(x, ' ~ Country')), Count.Whistle.type_ChiSq$n))$p.value)

#Set the names for the columns and rows in the distribution table 
chi_Country <- setNames(Chi_Whistle, Country)

#Chi-Square test
chi_Square_results<-lapply(chi_Country, chisq.test)
chi_Square_results
```

Many thanks in advance

**Reproducible Dataframe**

```
#Dummy data
#Create a cluster column with dummy data (clusters = 3)
f1 <- gl(n = 2, k=167.5); f1

#Produce a data frame for the dummy level data
f2<-as.data.frame(f1)

#Rename the column f2
colnames(f2)<-"Country"

#How many rows
nrow(f2)

#Rename the levels of the dependent variable 'Country' as classifiers
#prefer the inputs to be factors
levels(f2$Country) <- c("France", "Germany")

#Add a vector called Whistle Types
#Add a vector called Behaviors
Whistle_Types<-sample(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
                     'E', 'F'), 335, replace=TRUE)

#Create random numbers
Start.Freq<-runif(335, min=1.195110e+02, max=23306.000000)
End.Freq<-runif(335, min=3.750000e+02, max=65310.000000)
Delta.Time<-runif(335, min=2.192504e-02, max=3.155762)
Low.Freq<-runif(335, min=6.592500e+02, max=20491.803000)
High.Freq<-runif(335, min=2.051000e+03, max=36388.450000)
Peak.Freq<-runif(335, min=7.324220+02, max=35595.703000)
Center.Freq<-runif(335, min=2.190000e-02, max=3.155800)
Delta.Freq<-runif(335, min=1.171875+03, max=30761.719000)
Delta.Time<-runif(335, min=2.192504e-02, max=3.155762)

#Bind the columns together
Bind<-cbind(f2, Start.Freq, End.Freq,  Low.Freq, High.Freq, Peak.Freq,  Center.Freq, Delta.Freq, Delta.Time, Whistle_Types)

#Rename the columns 
colnames(Bind)<-c('Country', 'Low.Freq', 'High.Freq', 'Start.Freq', 'End.Freq', 'Peak.Freq', 'Center.Freq', 
                  'Delta.Freq', 'Delta.Time',"Whistle_Type")

#Produce a dataframe
Whistle_Parameters<-as.data.frame(Bind)
```

Comment: Do you know that the chi-square test can be applied to k x n tables, not just 2 x 2 tables? So you could test for differences across all whistle types with a single test. This would avoid the multiplicity problems inherent with your current approach, though the hypothesis being tested is slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not sure about your desired output. What p-values do you want to show for each combination of country x whistle type?

We can easily calculate *one* p-value which tests the hypothesis whether there are difference in the distribution of whistle type by country.

This is similar to the first example in the docs of `?chisq.test()`.

For this we just need the `Whistle_Parameters` data and we can use `table()` to create a contingency table which we can then use as input for `chisq.test()`.

We can find the first example of the docs in  `?chisq.test()` in [Agresti, A. (2007)](https://mregresion.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/agresti-introduction-to-categorical-data.pdf) on page 38.

```r
freq_tbl <- table(Whistle_Parameters$Country, Whistle_Parameters$Whistle_Type) 
freq_tbl
#>          
#>            A  B  C  D  E  F
#>   France  28 24 29 25 24 38
#>   Germany 35 32 21 19 40 20

chisq.test(freq_tbl)
#> 
#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 
#> data:  freq_tbl
#> X-squared = 13.602, df = 5, p-value = 0.01834
```

The random data with `set.seed()`

```r
set.seed(123)
#Dummy data
#Create a cluster column with dummy data (clusters = 3)
f1 <- gl(n = 2, k=167.5); f1
#>   [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#>  [38] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#>  [75] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [112] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [149] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#> [186] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#> [223] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#> [260] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#> [297] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#> [334] 2 1
#> Levels: 1 2

#Produce a data frame for the dummy level data
f2<-as.data.frame(f1)

#Rename the column f2
colnames(f2)<-"Country"

#How many rows
nrow(f2)
#> [1] 335

#Rename the levels of the dependent variable 'Country' as classifiers
#prefer the inputs to be factors
levels(f2$Country) <- c("France", "Germany")

#Add a vector called Whistle Types
#Add a vector called Behaviors
Whistle_Types<-sample(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
                        'E', 'F'), 335, replace=TRUE)

#Create random numbers
Start.Freq<-runif(335, min=1.195110e+02, max=23306.000000)
End.Freq<-runif(335, min=3.750000e+02, max=65310.000000)
Delta.Time<-runif(335, min=2.192504e-02, max=3.155762)
Low.Freq<-runif(335, min=6.592500e+02, max=20491.803000)
High.Freq<-runif(335, min=2.051000e+03, max=36388.450000)
Peak.Freq<-runif(335, min=7.324220+02, max=35595.703000)
Center.Freq<-runif(335, min=2.190000e-02, max=3.155800)
Delta.Freq<-runif(335, min=1.171875+03, max=30761.719000)
Delta.Time<-runif(335, min=2.192504e-02, max=3.155762)

#Bind the columns together
Bind<-cbind(f2, Start.Freq, End.Freq,  Low.Freq, High.Freq, Peak.Freq,  Center.Freq, Delta.Freq, Delta.Time, Whistle_Types)

#Rename the columns 
colnames(Bind)<-c('Country', 'Low.Freq', 'High.Freq', 'Start.Freq', 'End.Freq', 'Peak.Freq', 'Center.Freq', 
                  'Delta.Freq', 'Delta.Time',"Whistle_Type")

#Produce a dataframe
Whistle_Parameters<-as.data.frame(Bind)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, I made this harder in my mind than it was. I really have appreciated your help.